# Use a dynamic variable as a firebase element Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have 4 kinds of elements in my database, I send it back in props, and I would like to use `${tickettype}` as element to update in my database. So I don't know if I put the right symbols but I have an error on the first tickettype

```
fire
      .firestore()
      .collection("user")
      .doc(user.uid).update ({
        `${tickettype}`: `${tickettype} + ${ticketnumber}`
      });
```

[image]Thanks for time.

Comment: Could you please display the error?

Comment: Just added screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to name an object's property based on the content of a variable, you should use the [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) syntax:

```
{
  [tickettype]: `${tickettype} + ${ticketnumber}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks solve for it, and I have another problem.

The second ${tickettype} come from props

```
const tickettype = location.state.tickettype;

[`${tickettype}`]: `${tickettype} + ${ticketnumber}`
```

But ${tickettype} is showing a data like that : "ticketadcopy" At the base ticketadcopy is a constant called in usestate from the firebase database

```
  const [tadcopy, setTAdcopy] = useState('');
  const [tvideos, setTVideos] = useState('');
  const [tdescriptions, setTDescriptions] = useState('');
  const [tthumbnails, setTThumbnails] = useState('');
```

For the moment, the function arrives in my database as "the value of the props ${tickettype} + a number from ${ticketnumber},

What I would like is that since ${tickettype} will return a value of type "ticketvideos", "ticketadcopy".... that it considers ${tickettype} as the constant tadcopy for example and that when I import to firebase, it gives me :

For example tadcopy = 5
and ${ticketnumber} = 3

5 + 3 = 8

For the moment, it shows me "tadcopy + 3

[image]

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do. I can only advise you to give a look at template strings on MDN, and then open a new question if some code does not behave the way you expect: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: What I would like is that in my second ${tickettype} the ${tickettype} be considered as a raw text to be associated to the call of a state because the value of ${tickettype} makes one of my states